# Is there an in-universe explanation for why so many alien planets have names from human mythology?

Tags: star-trek

Romulus, Vulcan, Kronos, Orion,... and many other examples in the Star Trek universe.
Is there a reason why they all have names from Roman and Greek mythology? 
is there a reason for that ? Are they just using Federation (human) designations when in fact they have different names in their respective culture's native languages?

Comment: Apparently it’s Qo’nos?

Comment: Star Trek was a TV show aimed at a US audience and Western audience with at least some familiarity with Greek and Roman mythology'

Comment: @ab2 Yes, but is there an in-universe retcon?

Comment: Do we know for certain that "Vulcan" in vulcan is "Vulcan", and that it's not just the universal translator's rendition?

Comment: I must stop answering questions after I Have taken a sleeping pill.

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged [tag:ancient-aliens]?

Comment: I'm sure I remember a real planet called Vulcan, I think it was a theorized rouge planet in our solar system. I wonder if that's where the writers or GR got the idea.

Comment: Mars is the 'rouge' planet in our solar system ;)

Comment: @n00dles, [Vulcan is a small hypothetical planet that was proposed to exist in an orbit between Mercury and the Sun. Attempting to explain peculiarities of Mercury's orbit, the 19th-century French mathematician Urbain Le Verrier hypothesized that they were the result of another planet, which he named "Vulcan".](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulcan_(hypothetical_planet))

Comment: Many of those names are most likely translation conventions. Either because the native name is unpronounceable (likely including Vulcan, as Spock mentions his real name is also unpronounceable to non-vulcans), or because the UT adapts cultural mythological names for similar concepts in the native language.

Comment: The most reasonable answer is that each race uses its own names for the planets.  Vulcans have a name for their own planet, and use it among themselves.  The humans call it Vulcan because they can't pronounce its real name.  You see this on Earth among the different countries.  "Germany" is "Deutschland" for Germans, and "Alemania" to people in Spain.

Comment: @ThePopMachine That's the one!

Comment: @delinear I'ma blame that one on fatiuge :D

Comment: The planets would have been named by Earth scientists long before we made contact with the inhabitants. @JRE Yeah, wouldn't the UT translate their version of the planet name into the listeners' when they speak it. So as I think ench said, they (e.g Vulcans) are actually saying the name in *their* tongue. It's just being translated for the listener. We as the audience I think always hear the translated versions (?)

Comment: Answer:  See Stargate SG-1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many of the similarities in names can be put down to the viewer only hearing the *Earth* name for their planet and species. Per [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vulcan_(planet)):

> The Worlds of the Federation (p. 18) gives T'Khasi as Vulcan's
>   indigenous name and states that Terran astronomers, taking inspiration
>   from Terran mythology, provided the planet with its name of Vulcan,
>   which the Vulcans gracefully accepted as the planet's official
>   Federation designation.

It makes sense. Suppose we did find sentient life on the planet Mars tomorrow. Would we call them Fshdyf'ahgjio'FG? Or Martians?

Even thinking in terms of Earth languages, people rarely refer to the *Française*, we just call them the French. There's no social expectation that foreigner are named in their own tongue (and indeed, Spock mentions that even his own name is unpronounceable to humans).

Presumably Vulcan was named by Earth astronomers for its barren, hot landscape. Romulus would be named for its close proximity to Remus, the other planet in its system. Orion presumably orbits one of the actual stars that make up the constellation Orion (whose scientific names are Alpha Orionis, Beta Orionis, and so on).

The name of the Klingon homeworld is technically Qo'noS, not Kronos. Presumably we're made to believe that in-universe, it's coincidental that the pronunciation is so close to yet another mythological figure.

Answer (score 7):

According to *Star Trek*, Olympian Gods are actually aliens who traveled to Earth in ancient times which resulted in the Greek Mythology we see today. In *Star Trek: The Original Series* S02E04, Kirk and the crew even met Apollo (Son of Zeus) on Pollux IV.

[image]

[image]

It's very much possible that Olympian gods (and, other gods from different mythologies) have influenced lots of different alien cultures across the cosmos. So, it shouldn't be surprising if we see alien planets having name from human mythology.